# Reboot without sudoer privileges?

Tags: 10.10, command-line, reboot, dbus

I've been trying to get my ubuntu restart without having to edit the sudoers.
This has been possible before (in lucid I think) using a dbus command:

```
dbus-send –system –print-reply –dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

But this gives me an error. Looks like things have changed.

In KDE (which I don't use) one has something similar (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1871/how-can-i-safely-shutdown-reboot-logout-kde-from-the-command-line/1876#1876))

Could anyone show me an alternative way to make my machine reboot from a script (without adjusting rights)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Launchpad Question #85949](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/85949):

> **Logout**
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
> ```
>
> **Reboot**
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.RequestReboot
> ```
>
> **Shutdown**
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.RequestShutdown
> ```
>
> If some application is inhibiting logout/reboot/shutdown, no action will be performed and gnome-session will show a confirmation dialog.

So add the command:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

to your script.

**UPDATE:** The DBus interface for suspend and hibernate has been [removed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/554899), to suspend and hibernate from the command line, use pmi.

```
sudo apt-get install powermanagement-interface
```

- Suspend:

  ```
  pmi action suspend
  ```
- Hibernate:

  ```
  pmi action hibernate
  ```

Comment: where did you get these commands from?

Comment: @Quamis There is a link at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get of pmi in 10.10,
installs powermanagement-interface,
when `pmi action suspend` or `pmi action hibernate` called, returns ServiceUnknown error