# How can you log out via the terminal?

Tags: command-line, logout

Is there a terminal command that will log you out of your current desktop session and take you back to the login screen?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

## 11.10 and above

```
gnome-session-quit
```

## 11.04 and previous versions

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

(via [[image]DoR](http://chat.askubuntu.com/transcript/message/24349#24349), see [his answer to "Reboot without sudoer privileges?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15428/reboot-without-sudoer-privileges/15430#15430) for more dbus goodness!)

or alternatively, you can use

```
gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

`--force-logout` in contrast to just `--logout` will not ask the user to deal with unsaved documents and so on.

> is this the easiest way? no simple one
>   line command like sudo logout?? I will
>   never remember all that.

Yes, there is a command called logout, but it concerns the Terminal. gnome-session-save is the program that actually quits the `gnome-session`, which you can of course kill, but that wouldn't qualify as logging out. :-)

Notice as well that these commands don't require you to be root.

You can always add an **alias** to your system if you want to have a shorter command.

Open `~/.bash_aliases` with a text editor, or create it if it isn't there, and add something like this to it:

```
alias logout-gnome="gnome-session-save --force-logout"
```

(.bashrc is a script that is run every time a new [virtual terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal/14294#14294) is started up, you should set up all your permanent aliases there, see also: [How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/))

Comment: Well, there's always Ctrl-Alt-Backspace (if you enable it), but again that's killing the session rather than logging out from it.

Comment: You might want to add DISPLAY=:0.0 or similar when trying to log out of a session from ssh or another terminal.

Comment: It seems to me that "--force-logout" doesn't quite work, as it gives this error: WARNING **: Unable to start: Unknown option --force-logout. After digging around with `man gnome-session-quit`, I found that "--force" and "--logout" are actually meant to be different arguments. Therefore, "--force --logout" (two minus sings before "force" and "logout", with a space between) would be better as you won't have errors. At least, that's the case with Ubuntu 13.04 and Linux Mint 15. IDK about other/older versions of either distro.

Comment: aaronfranke@aaron-xub16desk$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: To state the (non-)obvious: for Ubuntu MATE-users, that's `mate-session-save --force-logout`

Comment: Thanks. `gnome-session-quit` works fine in Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 117):

I had installed mate desktop and none of the menus worked, even the f-keys didn't work.
I managed to get xterm through browsing with file manager.

The only thing that worked was :

```
sudo pkill -u username
```

Comment: I also did an alias out of it for me `alias ulogout="sudo pkill -KILL -u $1"`. Might come in handy for someone. Usage: `ulogout user_name`

Comment: @Eugene How about `alias logout="sudo pkill -u ${USER}"`?

Comment: This is a great solution for VM's like in Virtualbox.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the `sudo`?  Also, I think this is different than logging out, since it will kill *all* of your processes (for instance, if you have another remote session, it will also be killed).  I'm also not sure that it will necessarily kill all of your processes (I can imagine it might kill itself first?)  Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: For mate, use `mate-session-save --force-logout`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/641521/419514).

Comment: Great tip! This is the only method that works if Unity didn't startup properly. And as mentioned, you don't need the sudo part.

Comment: I was running another ubuntu 22 LTS in virtual box & one ISO download via torrent in brave browser, And system froze, couldn't logout to shutdown via UI options, the 'genome-session-quit' also didn't help, But your suggestion helped, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 34):

## 11.10 and above

Here's my personal solution!

In the terminal, run:

```
gedit ~/.bash_aliases
```

And add:

```
alias log-out="gnome-session-quit"
```

to the file! Now you just have to run log-out!

Answer (score 15):

Looks like `gnome-session-save` was renamed to `gnome-session-quit` for 11.10. Everything else in the main answer should still work with that single change.

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-February/msg00147.html

Answer (score 15):

For gnome sessions, `gnome-session-quit` works well.  By default it asks for confirmation and then logs you out (i.e., the `--logout` argument is assumed unless overridden with `--power-off` explicitly).   You can also tell the command to not prompt for confirmation on logout:

```
--no-prompt
      End the session without user interaction. This only works with --logout.
```

`gnome-session-quit` is still valid in 12.04.

Since the OP didn't specify the window/desktop manager, and the gnome-session-quit might not work with all possibilities, here's a generic X-windows way to return to the login screen or chooser which I've used several times over the last several releases:

From a terminal (invoked with, variously, 'Alt-F2 + xterm, or Ctrl-T, or Crt-Alt-F1, or by right-clicking on the desktop in Nautilus and using the "open in terminal" shortcut, etc.) type

`sudo pkill X`

This is generally overkill for most situations.   I tend to use it when I've got a hung process or when I've got to log out quickly.  When I've done this, Ubuntu has politely returned me to the login screen by re-spawning X-windows.

I've not yet used the `power-off` feature of the `gnome-session-quit`, as I typically use `shutdown -P now` for that purpose.

Answer (score 12):

On Xubuntu (or whenever using an Xfce session), you can logout via the terminal by using

```
xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

You must specify `--logout` or the logout confirmation screen will be displayed. This will work whether you have specified 'Xubuntu session' or 'Xfce session' when you logged in with `Lightdm`, as the session is still managed by the Xfce session manager.

In addition, another option will log you out as well:

```
xfce4-session-logout --fast
```

If this command is issued the session is not saved, so it is normally best to use `xfce4-session-logout --logout`.

The ability to logout using the terminal will be very useful to you, as will the other options such as suspend that are available with `xfce4-session-logout`.

For more information, see `man xfce4-session-logout` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xfce4-session-logout.1.html).

Comment: Confirmed, this also holds true for any Ubuntu Studio flavors.

Answer (score 10):

You can use below command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: That hard kills all running X sessions, for all users.

Comment: in `~/.bash_aliases` write `alias logmeout="service lightdm restart"`

Answer (score 9):

For Ubuntu Mate use `mate-session-save --force-logout`. It is like `gnome-session-quit`.

Answer (score 7):

I tried `gnome-session-quit --force` and it works!

Note: I use ubuntu 15.04

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: This one works in every case.

Answer (score 5):

lubuntu 12.10 LXDE running on a Samsung netbook (CPU: 1.66 GHZ Intel Atom; RAM: 2GB)

The below two commands logged me out immediately:

```
sudo pkill -u username
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want to kill your session, you can go back to the login screen using:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

If you select your user and enter your password, the session will be resumed, so it's not a full logout.

Answer (score 2):

And in kubuntu 12.04+ it is:

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a function by adding the following line to your .bashrc, then invoke by typing **logoff** at the shell prompt.

```
  logoff() { gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt ; } # Log Out
```

Comment: With Ubuntu 23.10 I use `logout() { gnome-session-quit --no-prompt ; }` without the `--logout` option. This way applications ask to save documents before exit and browser don't ask to recover when logged back in. Defining an alias also works: `alias logout-gnome="gnome-session-quit --no-prompt"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way which will work whether you are running X or you are in a TTY. There you go:

- If you use `lightdm`

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```
- if you use `gdm` or in Ubuntu GNOME

  ```
  sudo service gdm restart
  ```
- If you use `kdm` or in Kubuntu

  ```
  sudo service kdm restart
  ```

The downside of this command is that it will ask for your password.

Answer (score -1):

I found this accidentally.

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~/go/bin$ who -uH
NAME     LINE         TIME             IDLE          PID COMMENT
luvpreet tty7         2017-12-27 17:33  old        27458 (:0)
```

Here you get the process id of your current session.

So, easy. Kill it

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~$ kill 27458
```

There you go.