# Where's the "log out" option after clicking the power icon?

Tags: 11.04, unity, menu, live-usb

So the [documentation says](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html):

> To log out or switch users, click the
>   power icon on the top bar and select
>   the appropriate option.

However, I cannot see the "log out" option. All I see are:

- Lock Screen
- Switch from ubuntu
- Suspend
- Restart...
- Shut Down
- System settings

I managed to log out via a [terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal). **Any way to log out via the Unity GUI or add this option to the power icon menu?**

**update:** I'm running from a live USB.

Comment: Are you on a live USB or CD? If so then that's one case where that option isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open `gconf-editor` (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gconf-editor`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Navigate to `/apps/indicator-session/`
- Make sure none of the checkboxes on the right pane are ticked:

  [image]

However, it would be interesting to know why that happened (maybe worth reporting a bug).

Comment: Yay! That worked~