# Ubuntu automatically logs in to netbook version, have no options on desktop

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-netbook, auto-login

I am running Ubuntu 10.4 and tried to install unity, the website i found advised me to install netbook-remix.  Every time i boot it automatically logs into the netbook version without asking for a password and them i am stuck with no menu, icons etc.. All i'm able to do is access the terminal through keyboard shortcut but i have no idea how to set ubuntu to log in to gnome from the terminal.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can [get back to the login screen from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal). From there you *should* be able to select a session type and that *should* persist.

If it doesn't persist, then when you do it manually, load up the Login Screen Settings from System → Administration → Login Screen and set it there.