# How to log out with a command in a gnome-less environment?

Tags: desktop-environments, logout, gnome-session, display-manager

I installed various window managers (Awesome, dwm, etc.) from which I am not able to log out back to the login screen (gnome-session) in order to switch to another window manager. I need to reboot to do that, which is a waste of time (and can lead to data corruption).

Question [How can you log out via the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal) didn't work..

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

..neither did this:

```
gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

..nor that:

```
gnome-session-quit --force-logout
```

**they all returned:**

```
Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Is there a quick way to log out back into Gnome's session manager from a non-Gnome desktop manager using a terminal emulator? I know that CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE can be configured to restart X, but I'm looking for the easiest way to log out.

Comment: Could you not just log out by just quitting the WM - i.e Mod4+Shift+Q for awesome?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could restart the desktop manager, which is similar to restarting X.

On Ubuntu 11.10:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

On earlier versions:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

If that fails or you are on a very old system, try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

One of these should take you back to the login screen.  Be aware that you will not be prompted, so save any work before running this command!

Comment: This kills *all* connected users. Not always what you want.

Answer (score 10):

`<modkey> + shift + q` is the default command for killing the wm client on dwm and awesome. This effectively returns to the logout screen. Tested on a MacBook Air XUbuntu 12.10 with dmw, where it is alt + shift + q.Tested on a ThinkPad running Debian Stretch with awesome 3.5.

Comment: To switch users leaving the session open, one can use `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` or Ctrl + Alt + F{7,8}. Tested on Xubuntu 13.04 + i3.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04 you can use

```
/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout
```

It opens a dialog box. I use it with Awesome Window Manager.

To directly logout, you can also (softly) kill your window manager.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit  --logout --no-prompt
```

This works for me in an Awesome WM Gnome session. Since GNOME 3.10 or so the --logout --no-prompt is now needed because I guess the dialog box is gone.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's a good way of doing it, but:

```
kill -9 -1
```

Comment: This just kills everything. Dangerous.  Do not run this unless you are sure.

Answer (score -4):

Try this::

killall -u username

Comment: That'll send the regular SIGTERM signal to all processes at the same time rather than a graceful termination of the desktop environment as it should. This is different in terms of applications asking you to save your work or not. In a case of unsaved work this results in possible loss of that data compared to regular log out. So, -1.

Comment: Read what the person asking the question is trying to accomplish before giving your opinion:  " (...) I need to reboot to do that, which is a waste of time".  If he needs to reboot, the efect on unsaved work is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: Still, killall command works and is very useful when you don't have other ways like when the interface freezes.

Comment: Silvio, yes, you're right, but the user you're answering *may* not know the impact of what he's doing and *the next newbie on the block* looking for an easy answer *will definitely not know that*.  So if you rephrase your answer with the potential disadvantages and that [Ctrl][Alt][Backspace] is a better solution *but* that your solution is better then a reboot, I'm pretty sure Gert and me will *upvote* your answer instead of downvoting it. ;-)

Comment: **Note to Flaggers:** Do not mark technically incorrect and/or "bad" answers as "low quality". The downvote button is there for a reason.