# Ubuntu UI unresponsive but can ssh in, how do I log out the remote over ssh?

Tags: gnome, ssh, gnome-terminal, logout, gnome-session

I want to log out the user session of a remote Ubuntu 12.04 x64 (laptop) by ssh'ing and running a command.

I know I can reboot with a simple `sudo reboot` but don't want to if I can help it, I'd rather just log out and back in.

`gnome-session-quit` fails with an error that it can't find the display, and `gnome-session-quit DISPLAY=:0.0` also fails with the error:

```
> gnome-session-quit DISPLAY=:0.0

** (gnome-session-quit:20214): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=429980f04422a721b1ae90a50000000d --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

** (gnome-session-quit:20214): WARNING **: Unable to start: Cannot open display:
```

[Only other thread I could find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal#comment333939_15796) similar to this doesn't have any more answers than what I've tried.  Anyone know the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the value of the DISPLAY variable before the command - you will also need to specify options `--logout --no-prompt` else it will prompt for confirmation on the local display

```
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

If that fails, provided you have administrator privileges you could always just restart the display manager e.g. `sudo service lightdm restart` (although that will terminate ALL its managed sessions).

Obviously you should verify that the display number really is :0 if you have not already done so

Comment: Thanks, how do you check the display number?  Took a wild guess and `echo $DISPLAY` wasn't it.

Comment: The $DISPLAY variable won't be set automatically if you're in an SSH session - you can look for the X server process(es) /usr/bin/X in the output of the `ps` command, usually the primary server runs in tty7 so `ps -ef | grep '[t]ty7'` for example