# how to logout from terminal in 13.10?

Tags: command-line, logout

I have seen some previous post about logout from terminal but those were for old versions. I didnt find the way for logout in Ubuntu 13.10 from terminal.

How can I logout from terminal in Ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: Typing `exit` doesn't work?

Comment: Ctrl-D? (Feel like I'm missing something in this question...)

Comment: @ToDo exit will close the terminal but dont do logout. CTRL+D for closing a process not for logout.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal don't work?

Comment: @Takkat section missing for 13.04 and 13.10

Comment: **"... and above"** should include all releases greater than 11.10 (12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04 ...) - if any of these procedures stopped working we'd urgently need to edit the answers there to say so.

Comment: If you've seen a previous post ***and you've tested it***, make sure you a link to it and show us what didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

`gnome-session-quit --no-prompt` will log you out of an existing Unity session, without a prompt.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do a `killall -u <your-user-name>` to stop my current session and clean-up any remaining processes of mine.

Comment: cant to do this , because its not safe.

Comment: what is not safe about it?

Comment: http://aarklonlinuxinfo.blogspot.in/2008/07/kill-9-1.html

Comment: `killall -u <username>` will only kill the <user-name> processes (ie. no root-processes will be harmed). Additionally I don't say to kill it with `-9`. Your link doesn't relate to my answer *at all*.

Comment: @rajagenupula still not convinced yet? Please explain some more what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Well nothing , I miss read it . my fault.my post closed any way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a gnome / unity environment, you could use the `gnome-session-quit` command, you could use `gnome-session-quit --no-prompt` if you don't want to choose between lock or logout.

If you are in a pure terminal (no X-environment) `exit` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can use dbus signal to logout from the desktop, with `dbus-send`:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

Tested with gnome and unity.