# Simulate power button using command?

Tags: gnome, scripts, power-management, suspend

When I hit the power button on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04.1 without any modifications), I receive a pop window saying

`Goodbye, what would you like to do?
Lock Suspend Restart Shutdown`

How can I get this screen through command-line or a script?

Addition: The linked question mentions `gnome-session-quit` but this does not produce the overlay specified above: the accepted answer performs the desired behavior.

Comment: Usually commands are meant to reduce the graphical painting and speed up a process. but gnome-session-quit --power-off may help just like @Neon_overhead said

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you log out via the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal)

Comment: @OluDoug I understand this, but I was looking to create a custom shortcut to produce the overlay, rather than actually do this through the terminal.

Comment: Not a duplicate because this is about getting the "shut down" confirm screen, the other question is about logging out.  The similarity appears to be only that both involve using `gnome-session-quit`, just with different options.  While the OP may well decide the options in that other question are better, they don't address his specific need to see the shut down confirm screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you expect?

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

Alternatively there are some [other options to gnome-session-quit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gnome-session-quit.1.html).