# What file specifies the desktop environment for a user?

Tags: unity, login-screen, lxde, auto-login

I'm having problems with Unity on a slow laptop, but it's configured to autologin so I never see the login screen. Also, the screen or display driver is messed up so I don't see the far right part of the display.

I had already installed Lubuntu/LXDE earlier and I'd like to try logging into that instead -- but I can't get back to the login screen to set that as the desktop system for the user. The logout command [gnome-session-quit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal) doesn't work; I end up in the screen "the system is running in low-graphics mode".

The setting for a given user's desktop environment (Unity vs LXDE) is presumably in some text file somewhere. So if I could edit that file and then force a reboot, I'd achieve my goal. Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the auto login behavior of lightdm 
edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`  using `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

It should look something like this

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false 
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

Comment all the  line containing autologin. Next time you will get login screen.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 you may find this file empty, Simply add fillowing line in it

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=
```

Save and exit.

Comment: 14.04 onwards lightdm.conf is empty by default. Separate files in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` are used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that. But we should not edit the config in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d ` however we can override those settings in  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file. I am adding this point  in my answer.

Comment: You are supposed to add files to that folder, not edit files there or edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.