# How to run logout with cron?

Tags: shutdown, cron, logout

I'm creating something to allow me to set limits for time spent per user session: I've created a *cron* job:

```
*/120 * * * 1,2,3,4,5 /path/to/command
*/180 * * * 0,6 /path/to/command
```

and I want to run `logout` (and possibly *shutdown* as there's a BIOS password set), could someone tell me how to run both of those via *cron*?.

Comment: Still looking for help, just need the system path of the logout script?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal

Answer (score 3):

```
*/150 * * * 0,6 gnome-session-quit
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As [Pavel Selivanov](https://github.com/selivan) points out in this [article](https://selivan.github.io/2016/07/08/notify-send-from-cron-in-ubuntu.html) it is necessary to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `DISPLAY` to enable gui related tasks from a cronjob.

He has written a shell script, which gets the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for XFCE, Gnome, Unity, Cinnamon and KDE. I can confirm that is works under `ubuntu:16.04`.

`$ sudo nano /usr/local/bin/gui-cron`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ "$#" -lt 1 ] && echo "Usage: $0 program options" && exit 1

program="$1"
shift

user=$(whoami)
env_reference_process=$( pgrep -u "$user" xfce4-session || pgrep -u "$user" cinnamon-session || pgrep -u "$user" gnome-session || pgrep -u "$user" gnome-shell || pgrep -u "$user" kdeinit )

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /proc/"$env_reference_process"/environ | grep -z ^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//')
export DISPLAY=$(cat /proc/"$env_reference_process"/environ | grep -z ^DISPLAY= | sed 's/DISPLAY=//')
"$program" "$@"
```

Then one can create a user cronjob that runs by a given schedule with the crontab syntax. Here e.g. every 15 minutes between 22:00 and 05:59:

`$ crontab -e`

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/15 22-23,00-05 * * * gui-cron gnome-session-quit --power-off
```