# How can I change user from command line

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, openbox

I'm in Lubuntu with Openbox as DE. When I press the power button, a window pops up and displays multiple options: logout, hibernate, sleep, change user etc.

However, sometimes nothing happens when I press this button. I supose that all these actions can be achieved via the command line. For example I can suspend with `pm-suspend`.

What is the command used to return to the login screen/display manager to change users? I am not interested in actually changing my user, I just want to login again. I do this to fix a problem with the mouse cursor.

What is the name of the default application that is lauched when a user presses the power button in Lubuntu?

Comment: I believe the options that pop-up when you press the button are related to `gnome-settings-daemon` but not entirely sure. Try opening the session first, pressing power button. If nothing happens, try starting `gnome-settings-daemon` and pressing it again

Comment: There is [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/15795/178596) which discusses how to logout via command line (in Unity/Gnome though...). What you are probably looking for is something that restarts the DE/Window Manager, like 'Alt'+'F2'+`r` does in GNOME 3 (might be `openbox --restart` or something - not a clue as probably haven't used openbox :)

Comment: ... or `openbox --reconfigure` ([source](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=2752))

Comment: @Serg Nothing happens. `gnome-settings-daemon` is not installed in Lxde by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This also works in Lubuntu 15.04 with LightDM as display manager:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

Comment: Not sure who down-voted, but this works, so I evened it out

Answer (score 4):

Lightdm controls the login window.

You need to access a terminal, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then login as any user with `sudo` (root) privileges.

You will be presented with a command prompt. The only command you need is this:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

And it will show. Note that all users currently logged in will be logged out.

---

If you don't want users to be logged out, you may need a different command. Login to the terminal you accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as the user you want to login as.

Then simply run this command:

```
startx
```

and you will be logged in as that user. To switch between the 2 logged in users, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: beaten me by a fraction of a second:) +1

Comment: @serg 2 seconds in it :P +1 to you btw :)

Answer (score 3):

> I am not interested in actually changing my user, I just want to login again. I do this to fix a problem with the mouse cursor.

If you want to login again, open `tty` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, login there, and type `sudo service lightdm restart` . You can do it in terminal app,too, but this is my preferred way - hence suggesting. Your session will be closed and you will be returned to login screen

I believe the options that pop-up when you press the button are related to `gnome-settings-daemon` but not entirely sure. Try opening the session first, pressing power button. If nothing happens, try starting `gnome-settings-daemon` and pressing it again.

There is also `gnome-session-quit` command, but I am unsure if this will work in openbox unless `gnome-settings-daemon` is started