# How to log out from a session using the command line?

Tags: command-line, login, logout

In order to log out from a session in xfce4, I usually click onto the icon in the upper left corner, click onto a further icon captured as log out, thereupon a window opens, where I can choose between:

- log-out
- restart
- shutdown
- suspend

I click onto log-out and I am at the log-in shell.

Is there a way to get into this log-in shell without the clicking onto icons and buttons but by typing some commands inside the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can logout by typing `gnome-session-quit`.

There are other options as explained at this link: [How can you logout from the terminal.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal)