# Non-root users to shutdown using PAM

Tags: shutdown, pam

I want to configure PAM to enable non-root normal users to be able to shutdown. how to do that?

I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04

---

I know how to do that with many ways such as changing permissions of the binary or adding exceptions in the sudeors....

I don't want to change permissions

I don't know to configure policykit

I don't want to give permissions from sudeors

**I need only to learn how to do it by confiuring PAM not any onther method**

Comment: A desktop or server? The desktops mostly have DBUS/policykit interfaces that allow users to shut down... [These can be accessed from the command line in a stretch](http://askubuntu.com/q/15428/449).

Comment: @Oli I edit my question. I'm using server

Answer (score 0):

policykit also work on server, I'd suggest to modify (as root) the following file:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy
```

Look at actions like this one:

```
action id="org.freedesktop.login1.power-off"
```

And replace allow_any, allow_inactive, and allow_active values by **yes** to allow non root users to perform a power off without any authentication.

Comment: I want to use PAM not PolicyKit