# How can I safely shut down Xfce from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, shutdown, xfce

I'm not looking for `shutdown` or `reboot` or the like. I want to know how to shut down Xubuntu from the terminal, by executing a command that would have the same effect as clicking the "Shutdown" button in a menu.

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1871/how-can-i-safely-shutdown-reboot-logout-kde-from-the-command-line), but for Xubuntu/XFCE.

Comment: Similar as in shutting down form a gui: `sudo halt --poweroff`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think what you want is `xfce4-session-logout` ([online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xfce4-session-logout.1.html)).

Excerpt from the manpage (reformatted, filtered):

```
   The  xfce4-session-logout command allows you to programmatically logout
   from your Xfce session. It requests the session manager to display  the
   logout  confirmation  screen,  or,  if  given  one  of the command-line
   options below, causes the session manager to take the requested  action
   immediately.

OPTIONS:
   --logout     Log out without displaying the logout dialog.
   --halt       Halt without displaing the logout dialog.
   --reboot     Reboot without displaying the logout dialog.
   --suspend    Suspend without displaying the logout dialog.
   --hibernate  Hibernate without displaying the logout dialog.
   --fast       Do  a  fast shutdown.  This instructs the session manager not to
                save the session, but instead to quit everything quickly.
```

So to shut down, use

```
xfce4-session-logout --halt
```

and to reboot, use

```
xfce4-session-logout --reboot
```

If you just want to get the dialogue where you can pick an action manually, run it without arguments:

```
xfce4-session-logout
```

Comment: The same question was asked recently on U&L, do consider posting this answer there too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/758346/70524

Answer (score 1):

Check this also . It is a distribution independent, simple, bash script which depends only on `yad` and `systemctl`
https://gist.github.com/harish2704/25857caf89076d5a78e996df3fa6ac56